# How to search and auto-register all beans under a specific package

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have `x number` of `beans` under some `base-package` say com.mypackage.basepackage.

What I am trying to do is to `auto-scan` this package and register all the beans to `ApplicationContext` with `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`.

Here is how I am trying to do this.

```html
public class BeanRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor
{
 
 @Override
 public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException
 {
 }

 @Override
 public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException
 {
        //loop n-number of times and register all the scanned beans.
  BeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(scannedbeans.class, Autowire.BY_TYPE.value(), true);
  registry.registerBeanDefinition("beanName", beanDefinition);
 }
}
```

What I want is to loop on `com.mypackage.basepackage` , look for beans and register them.

I know I can scan `basepackage` with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.basepackage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html